# Stack forEach expression to loop for difference between existing size and new one

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a class with data member:

```
private static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 10;
private Stack<String> myStack = new Stack<>();

// want to add more element to the stack based on demand - but add incremental demand

public void addCapacity(int incremental) {
    int diff = incremental - DEFAULT_SIZE;
    myStack.forEach((diff) -> {
        myStack.push("something");
    });
}
```

The idea was to see if this forms a use case for lambda functions. But it will not allow me as it is expecting a `boolean` in place of `diff`. Is lambda `forEach` a use-case here?

Comment: Maybe because it s too early and/or I did not drink my coffee yet, but I don't know what you *want* your code to do, nor what problem are you facing (aside from fact that you are using forEach in which you attempt to modify that collection which may lead to ConcurrentModificationException). Could you [edit] your question and clarity it more?

Comment: What do you expect different values of `diff` to do?

Comment: Maybe, I think you try to add elements with [Diff] variables count.
In that case, I recommend that you add it with a [for statement] or use [list.addAll].

Comment: @佐藤慧太 That’s right. Want to increase the stack capacity. And instead of running a loop, can we use lambda is the question. Yes, did with a regular loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Stack` extends `Vector`, if you wanted to increase the capacity, then you could have used `ensureCapacity` (in [Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#ensureCapacity-int-))

```java
myStack.ensureCapacity(minCapacity);
```

If you wanted to do `myStack.push("something")` `diff` times, then you could have used:

```java
IntStream.range(0, diff).forEach(i -> myStack.push("something"));
```